# Convert type of TranslateArrayResponse to string[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, microsoft-translator

I am working with Microsoft Translator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512422.aspx).
Specifically the `TranslateArray()` method which basically takes a string array of texts to translate and the result is an array with the translated text.

The resulting translation comes with a type of `TranslateArrayResponse[]`.
My code looks something like this (shortened down for clarity)

```
string[] sourceTranslate = new string[3] {"My name is Peter", "Her name is Suzan", "We have fun"};
....
TranslateArrayResponse[] result = client.TranslateArray("", sourceTranslate, "en", "de", options);
```

The challenge with the `client.TranslateArray()` method is that it only allows each request to be 10,000 characters and number items a maximum of 2000. My `sourceTranslate` (a resx file) easily contains more than 10,000 characters, so to get around this I am splitting up requests to fit these boundaries.

My question is how do I copy the value `result` to a string[] or similar - I need to work later with the `result` (i.e. saving the results back to a new resx file)?

Obviously stuff like `result += ...` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

A straightforward one is to create a new string step by step while looping over the array of `TranslateArrayResponse` values - according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512422.aspx), each of them has a `TranslatedText` property of type `string`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var tar in result) {
    sb.Append(tar.TranslatedText);
}
string resultString = sb.ToString();
```

Another solution is to use the LINQ [`Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract the translated text from each item and then the [`string.Join` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to concatenate the result enumeration of strings:

```
string resultString = string.Join("", result.Select(r => r.TranslatedText));
```

Comment: Perfect - just what I needed :)